# In SQL 2012 - Export Data-tire Application Error: Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server : . (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have asked to move Database from SQL server 2012 to azure SQL During the export data-tire Application Its shows Error :
Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac). Can anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi, During Export Data-tier application in SQL 2012, I receive the error "Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server : . (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)"

Comment: That's not a question, that's a statement (which I have already seen in your post). What is it that you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your SQL Server Management Studio version. I had a similar issue with SSMS version 11 (2012) exporting Data-tier application on a SQL 2019 database. Upgrading to SSMS version 19 (2019) enabled me to export without issues.
Reference: [SQL 2016 - Export Data Tier Application - Feature not Working](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2006743-sql-2016-export-data-tier-application-feature-not-working)